# How to get audience_size in Interest plus Country query

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-ads-api

Hi i'm still new in Facebook-ads-api I know this is a noob question,
I want to get the audience_size for the Interest in a specific country.
on the API sample it can only generate the whole world audience_size of an Interest

```
use FacebookAds\Object\TargetingSearch;
use FacebookAds\Object\Search\TargetingSearchTypes;

$results = TargetingSearch::search(
  TargetingSearchTypes::INTEREST,
  null,
  'soccer'
);
// Sample Response
{
   "data":[
      {
         "name":"Association football (Soccer)",
         "id":6003107902433,
         "audience_size":593326800,
         "path":[
            "Sports and outdoors",
            "Sports",
            "Association football (Soccer)"
         ],
         "description":null
      },
      ...other results...
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the estimated audience, you can use the Reach Estimate.
You can see the documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/reachestimate/

Just pass the targeting object (which include the interest and the country) and get the result.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I can't try this solution at the moment because I don't have a act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID> which I'm still trying to figure out where to find.

Comment: you can find your adaccounts ids by calling: /me?fields=adaccounts

Comment: it returned "(#278) Reading advertisements requires an access token with the extended permission ads_read"
I think I don't have an adaccounts yet. Thank you very much for the reply